# Meteor create different accounts with loginButtons

Tags: authentication, meteor, package, account

Is it possible to create different accounts with loginButtons in meteor?
It seems that I have to change the style of the form (such as add a check box wit option "teacher" and "student") and change the insert behavior in js. But the loginButtons seems to always create default users for us.so is it possible to change some files of account-ui or account-password packages to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're talking about account creation (sign-up) and not login.

You could easily write you own custom UI.
Build a template with a form containing your desired login, password, email and type (dropdown or checkbox). Then create an event for this template and on `click #register-button` you create a new user like this:

```
var user = {
    username: login,
    password: password,
    email: email,
    profile: {
        userType: type
    }
};
Accounts.createUser(user);
```

If the execution from the client side doesn't work (which I assume it doesn't depending on your security settings), you have to call a server method and handle the user creation there.

In case I missed the point, please have a look at [account section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api) of the Meteor documentation.